# RequireJS and Jquery-1.4.4, can not get jquery object in module

Tags: jquery, requirejs

My question:Why can not get jquery object in self defined module(bar.js below) ?

Description:
jquery is 1.4.4 which is a non-AMD version.

below is my HTML file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script data-main='scripts/init.js' src='./require.js'></script>
        <script>
            require.config({
                map : {
                    'bar' : {
                        'jquery' : 'jquery-1.4.4.min'
                    }
                },
                config : {
                    'foo' : {
                        entry : 'index.php'
                    },
                    'bar' : {
                        entry : 'default.html'
                    }
                },
                paths : {
                    'jquery' : 'jquery-1.4.4.min',
                    'backbone' : 'backbone-min',
                    'underscore' : 'underscore-min',
                },
                shim : {
                    'backbone' : {
                        'deps' : ['underscore', 'jquery'],
                        'exports' : 'xxoo'
                    },
                    'jquery' : {
                        'exports' : '$'
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='testDiv'>xxxx</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

init.js just load my module bar.js:

```
[user@fa01v /var/www/html/test/requirejs]$ cat scripts/init.js 
define(['bar'], function(bar){
    return;
});
```

In bar.js I'm trying to get jquery object like this:

```
[user@fa01v /var/www/html/test/requirejs]$ cat scripts/bar.js 
define(['module', 'jquery'], function(module, j){
    console.log(j);
});
```

I just got 'undefined' in firebug's console.But if I access the global object in bar.js like this:
console.log($)
I can get the right object.

What could this happen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your `map` and it should work. Your map is currently this:

```
           map : {
                'bar' : {
                    'jquery' : 'jquery-1.4.4.min'
                }
            },
```

This tells RequireJS "in the module `bar`, when there is a request for the module named `jquery`, then load the module named `jquery-1.4.4.min` instead. So when your `bar` module executes, it loads the module named `jquery-1.4.4.min` instead of `jquery`. Two consequences:

1. When RequireJS looks at `paths`, searches for `jquery-1.4.4.min` *which it does not find*. You have `jquery` among the keys of that mapping, not `jquery-1.4.4.min` (which does appear in the *values* but that does not help).

   However, here, the fact that RequireJS does not find `jquery-1.4.4.min` in the keys of `paths` is moot because it does what it does when it does not find something in path: it just adds `.js` at the end, combine it with the `baseUrl` and tries to load *this*, which works in your case.
2. RequireJS looks for a `shim` for `jquery-1.4.4.min`, and does not find one. **This is the problem.** This is why you get an `undefined` return value.

If you remove the `map` for `jquery`, when `bar` tries to load `jquery`, the `paths` will ensure that the right file is loaded, and the `shim` will ensure you get the proper return value.